# ¿como chequear si un decimal es menor o igual a un integer?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
   public bool CheckArena()
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(porcentajeArena.Text) >= 60 && Convert.ToDecimal(porcentajeArena.Text) <= 71)
        {
             error0.Text = "";
             return true;

        }
        else 
        {
            error0.Text = "Error. El campo Arena requiere de un valor entre 60% y 71%";
            }
```

Por textbox le paso por ejemplo 63.5 pero me tira el error diciendo que el valor debe estar entre 60 y 71.

Comment: verificaste el valor de Convert.ToDecimal(porcentajeArena.Text) ?

Comment: si, y esta correcto. Es 63.5

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la conversión puede ser errónea en función de la Cultura utilizada. Revisa las opciones de conversión y prueba a utilizar un InvariantCulture, a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: La verdad, el código mostrado no concuerda con el comportamiento descrito. Una posibilidad es que, como comenta @DaríoAlonso, falle la conversión y haya una excepción que capturas e ignoras en otra parte. Para asegurarte de que funciona: a) Prueba con un número entero (p.ej. 62) y b) Añade al mensaje de error el valor de `porcentajeArena.Text` para asegurarte de que se actualiza.

Comment: Si eso no te funciona puedes probar a cambiar Convert.ToDecimal por Double.Parse(porcentajeArena.Text) >= 60.0 y la otra comparación lo mismo. De todas maneras siempre está bien poner un try catch por si te salta una excepción. También tiene que tener en cuenta si en tu zona, los decimales se indican con punto (.) o con una coma (,)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas ingresando "63.5" y pasando el valor con un punto ".".
Para que te funcione correctamente la conversión deberías ingresar "63,5" el valor con una coma ","

Si no podes modificar desde el panel de control -> region -> configuración regional y de idioma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos